# How to count exploded array

Tags: php, arrays

My string looks like:

```
244.53.66=1,53.646.77=1,666.534.23=5,664.521.64=3,535.777.54=2,533.886=5,22.153=5,643.786=2
```

I exploded it like:

```
$string = "244.53.66=1,53.646.77=1,666.534.23=5,664.521.64=3,535.777.54=2,533.886=5,22.153=5,643.786=2";
    $array = explode(",", $string);
            $array2=array();
            for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++) 
            {
                array_push($array2, explode("=",$array[$i]));
            }
```

now $array2 got these values:

```
$array2[0][0] = "244.53.66";
$array2[0][1] = "1";
$array2[1][0] = "53.646.77";
$array2[1][1] = "1";
```

etc.

How Can I count all values each type, example:

2 x 1 (two records with value 1), 1x1(1 record with value 1) itd.

I want to store this as array:

```
$array3[index] = "amount same values";
```

Can You help me?

Comment: What would be the expected output from your current input array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to get the IDs in a seperate array, then use `array_count_values`to count the number of the IDs.

Here's the final code:

```
<?php
$string = "244.53.66=1,53.646.77=1,666.534.23=5,664.521.64=3,535.777.54=2,533.886=5,22.153=5,643.786=2";
$array = explode(",", $string);
$array2=array();
for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    array_push($array2, explode("=",$array[$i]));
}

$array3 = array();
//Iterate through array 2 to extract all IDs
for($i = 0; $i<count($array2); $i++)
{
   array_push($array3, $array2[$i][1]);
}
$vals = array_count_values($array3);
print_r($vals);
?>
```

Which outputs

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

Happy coding on StackOverflow !